# Formatting Reccuring Date String with a Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a little function I can't get pinned down. I would generally do this in application layer but don't have the option with it and my T-SQL is a little rusty.

Simplified Function:  (Take a date and calculate recurring dates on interval)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetRunDatesShort] 
      (@startDate DateTime, @weeks INTEGER) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @i INTEGER
   DECLARE @interval INTEGER
   DECLARE @outPut VARCHAR(500)

    SET @outPut = ''
    SET @i = 0
    SET @interval = 7

   WHILE (@i < @weeks)
    BEGIN
     SET @output = @outPut + ', ' + 
               Convert(varchar, DATEPART(MONTH, 
                  DATEADD(d, @interval, @startDate)),101) + '-'
             + Convert(varchar, DATEPART(d, 
                  DATEADD(d, @interval, @startDate)))
     SET @interval = @interval + 7
     SET @i = @i + 1
    END
   RETURN @output 
END
GO

SELECT dbo.fn_GetRunDatesShort(GETDATE(), 4)
```

So this returns

```
, 8-21, 8-28, 9-4, 9-11
```

I need to get this to return

```
August 21, 28 | September 4, 11
```

Comment: From other questions I can assume you're using SQL Server 2008, if so why not use DATE instead of DATETIME? Also could number of weeks ever approach 52 (meaning you may have two different Augusts in the output)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [avoid loops when you can generate sets much more efficiently](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1), and [*please* stop declaring `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Here is a function that combines both of your requirements (generate the set of dates and format them in your awkward output format):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetRunDatesShort_2
(
  @StartDate DATE, @Weeks TINYINT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX);

  ;WITH cte1(m,d) AS
  (
    SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, wd), CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DAY(wd)) FROM 
    (
      SELECT TOP (@Weeks) DATEADD(WEEK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (ORDER BY [object_id]), @StartDate)
      FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
    ) AS sq(wd)
  ),
  cte2(ds) AS
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT m + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + d FROM cte1 AS cte1_a 
      WHERE cte1_a.m = cte1.m
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','varchar(max)'),1,1,'') 
      FROM cte1
  )
  SELECT @output = STUFF((SELECT ' | ' + ds FROM cte2 
      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.[1]','varchar(max)'),1,3,'');

  RETURN (@output);
END
GO
```

(If you have a Numbers table - [which you should](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable) - you can replace the query against `sys.all_objects` to a similar one against the Numbers table, and then you can add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` to the function - which may not help in this case, but it's [something I try to do consistently whenever possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx).)

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_GetRunDatesShort_2(GETDATE(), 4);
```

Results:

```
August 21, 28 | September 4, 11
```

The problem comes if your `@weeks` approaches 52 - what output do you expect if you have dates from August of this year *and* dates from August of next year?

---

**EDIT 2014-05-19**

To ensure ordering in the right direction (something that worked okay last August, but seems to change order now in May), you can make this change to the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetRunDatesShort_2
(
  @StartDate DATE, @Weeks TINYINT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX);

  ;WITH cte1(mn,m,d) AS
  (
    SELECT 
      DATEPART(YEAR, wd) * 100 + DATEPART(MONTH, wd), 
      DATENAME(MONTH, wd), CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(DAY,wd)) 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT TOP (@Weeks) DATEADD(WEEK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          (ORDER BY [object_id]), @StartDate)
      FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id]
    ) AS sq(wd)
  ),
  cte2(mn,ds) AS
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT mn, m + STUFF((SELECT ', ' + d FROM cte1 AS cte1_a 
      WHERE cte1_a.m = cte1.m ORDER BY mn
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','varchar(max)'),1,1,'') 
      FROM cte1
  )
  SELECT @output = STUFF((SELECT ' | ' + ds FROM cte2 ORDER BY mn
      FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.[1]','varchar(max)'),1,3,'');

  RETURN (@output);
END
GO
```

Comment: wouldn't have a situation where dates were that far apart and I can check for that in the application code.  Do you have any resources to learn more about the ";WITH" statement ?  Thats a CTE  right ?  Thanks for the help and insight

Comment: I'm coming back to this code and have noticed that it puts the dates in the wrong order dbo.fn('2014-04-28', 5) would spit out 'June 2 | May 5, 12, 19, 26' instead of 'May 5, 12, 19, 26 | June 2' ... Where would I place the order clause to reverse the month order ?  (Figured I'd message you before starting a new question)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid going through the FOR XML engine, May I suggest some case statement structure?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetRunDatesShort_2
(
  @StartDate DATE, @Weeks TINYINT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @output = ''

SELECT @output = @output + CASE @output WHEN '' THEN M ELSE CASE R WHEN 1 THEN ' | ' + M ELSE '' END END + ' ' + CASE R WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE ', ' END + D
FROM (
    SELECT year(DT) as Y, datename(month,DT) as M, CAST(datepart(day,DT) AS VARCHAR) AS D
        , row_number()over(partition by month(DT), year(dt) order by day(DT)) AS R
        , row_number()over(order by dt) AS R2
    FROM (
        SELECT dateadd(ww,row_number()over(order by object_id), @StartDate) AS DT
        FROM master.sys.objects
    ) z
) y
WHERE R2 <= @weeks
ORDER BY R2

RETURN @output
END
GO
```

Output of `SELECT dbo.fn_GetRunDatesShort_2(GETDATE(),5)`

```
May 26 | June 2 , 9 , 16 , 23
```

This could also be edited in case year of the date becomes important to the output.